# Query the value of an item`s property of a JArray with json.net

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

My jsonarray has a serialized List of Products with Id and Name property.

```
JArray jsonarray  = JArray.Parse(json);

var name = // Get value for Name property which has Id 1.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try using linq:

```
JArray jsonarray = JArray.Parse("[{'Id':3, 'Name': 'Product3'}, {'Id':1, 'Name': 'Product1'}, {'Id':2, 'Name': 'Product2'}]");

var name = jsonarray
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value<int>("Id") == 1)
    .Value<string>("Name");
```

Note that you should perform null check because `FirstOrDefault` may return null if an element with property `Id == 1` is not found.

Answer (score 0):

```
 JArray jsonarray  = JArray.Parse(json);  
 var name = (string)jsonarray.Children().Single( p => (int)p["Id"] == 1)["Name"];
```

Catch the possible `InvalidOperationException` from `Single`